# .Net Chart Logarithmic Axis Scaling, unexpected scaling issues

Tags: .net, vba, visual-studio, charts, logarithm

I have an example chart with logarithmic scaling x axis and y axis as such,

[image]

Ok now if I set the min X value to say 48 I get

[image]

This is super unreadable, what I would prefer is to keep the 1, 10, 100, base 10 log scale, but essentially shift the starting point over if that make sense, so the graph above would look  more like....

[image]

(Pretend there is a Y axis in that photo)

A few examples I have Tried,

- playing around with Crossing property but that only affects where the x and y axis cross each other
- Playing around with scale view, but this runs into the save x-Axis scaling issue
- Trying to play with the interval-offset **I'm not sure if this won't work, but it's proving hard  to work with in a logarithmic scale

The end result of this will be a chart like this....
[image]

As Values update the Vertical line on the left side will update in position, however I want it to stay at a constant position and the image to essentially shift to accommodate that

I have looked through every property with regards to the chart Area, and Axis, but I cannot seem to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `Math.Log10` is required to calculate the `IntervalOffset` property.
Rather than hard-coding a whole set of numbers which all depend on the starting number, you can calculate these (including an offset for the `MinorGrid`, which will need to be different if you want the minor grid-lines between `chartMin` and the next order of 10). So, assuming a `Chart` object called `chart`, you need (in C#):

```
int chartMin = 48;
double logMin = Math.Log10 (chartMin);
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = chartMin;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = Math.Ceiling (logMin) - logMin;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Interval = 1;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.IntervalOffset = Math.Floor (logMin) - logMin;
```

[And the resulting X-axis looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU8An.png)

Answer (score 1):

The interval offset works on a rather non-intuitive scale whilst your in logarithmic scaling in the above instance setting the intervaloffset to

IntervalOffset = Math.log(100) - Math.log(48) 
to acheive the desired result

[image]